# How do I get "float" to work without leaving gaps between images?

Tags: html, css, floating, photo-gallery

Very new developer here, and I cannot seem to figure out what is happening with my code. I'm attempting to make a photogrid, and tried to get them to float first, but the images are leaving strange gaps that I don't understand.  Just trying to get them to be consistent, and can't figure out where I'm going wrong.  [large gaps in floating.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z3JX.png)

Here is my code:

HTML

```css
img {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%
}
h1  {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 1.66%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Photo Blog</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="photogrid.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <h1>Gabe's Decks</h1>
    
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/06/20/25/dog-3204497_960_720.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="RW Houndmaster. CURS.jpeg">
    <img src="RWg.jpeg">
    <img src="UR Can't Lose.jpeg">
    <img src="UR Mill copy.jpeg">
    <img src="UR Mill.jpeg">
    <img src="UR Prowess 3-0 (6-0).jpeg">
    <img src="UR Spells 4x overload.jpeg">
    <img src="UR Spells.jpeg">
    <img src="WRb creatures.jpeg">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please have a look to the answer fully updated

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that you fixed the height of the image but not the `height` So in demo 1 I made a wrong example as your image.

In the second demo, you can see that the height has been added and you dont have the gap anymore. But the problem is that the image format is not anymore respected. To keep the good format you need to includ your images into "container" that will keep the image in the best format.

In DEMO 3, you will see that we called "Grid system" I would recommand to take the time to read this: [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Relationship_of_Grid_Layout). The goal is to fix a container in order to make sure that the content will respect a certain format.

DEMO 4 is without main container only with your `float:left` on the image container.

So if I would be you I would look for DEMO 3 & 4

DEMO 1 WRONG: >>> Check Question <<<

DEMO 2 WORKS BUT IMAGE SIZE NOT RESPECTED :

```css
img {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
  height: 120px; /* Fix height like this */
  max-height: 120px; /* Fix height like this */
}
h1  {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 1.66%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Photo Blog</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="photogrid.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <h1>Gabe's Decks</h1>
    
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/06/20/25/dog-3204497_960_720.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="RW Houndmaster. CURS.jpeg">
    <img src="RWg.jpeg">
    <img src="UR Can't Lose.jpeg">
    <img src="UR Mill copy.jpeg">
    <img src="UR Mill.jpeg">
    <img src="UR Prowess 3-0 (6-0).jpeg">
    <img src="UR Spells 4x overload.jpeg">
    <img src="UR Spells.jpeg">
    <img src="WRb creatures.jpeg">
  </body>
</html>
```

DEMO 3 WITH IMG CONTAINER

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.containerIMG{
  width: 30%;
  height: 120px; /* Fix height like this */
  display:flex;
  margin: 1.66%;
}
img {
  
  /*float: left;*/
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;  /* Fix height like this */
  max-height: 100%; /* Fix height like this */
  margin:auto;
}
h1  {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 1.66%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Photo Blog</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="photogrid.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <h1>Gabe's Decks</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="containerIMG">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="containerIMG">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/06/20/25/dog-3204497_960_720.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="containerIMG">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="containerIMG">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="containerIMG">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="containerIMG">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="containerIMG">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="containerIMG">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="containerIMG">
        <img src="RW Houndmaster. CURS.jpeg">
      </div>
      <div class="containerIMG">
        <img src="RWg.jpeg">
      </div>
      <div class="containerIMG">
        <img src="UR Can't Lose.jpeg">
      </div>
      <div class="containerIMG">
        <img src="UR Mill copy.jpeg">
      </div>
      <div class="containerIMG">
        <img src="UR Mill.jpeg">
      </div>
      <div class="containerIMG">
        <img src="UR Prowess 3-0 (6-0).jpeg">
      </div>
      <div class="containerIMG">
        <img src="UR Spells 4x overload.jpeg">
      </div>
      <div class="containerIMG">
        <img src="UR Spells.jpeg">
      </div>
      <div class="containerIMG">
        <img src="WRb creatures.jpeg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

DEMO 4 WITH FLOAT LEFT

```css
.containerIMG{
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 120px; /* Fix height like this */
  display:flex;
  margin: 1.66%;
}
img {
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;  /* Fix height like this */
  max-height: 100%; /* Fix height like this */
  margin:auto;
}
h1  {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 1.66%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Photo Blog</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="photogrid.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <h1>Gabe's Decks</h1>
    <div class="containerIMG">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="containerIMG">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/06/20/25/dog-3204497_960_720.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="containerIMG">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="containerIMG">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="containerIMG">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="containerIMG">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="containerIMG">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="containerIMG">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="containerIMG">
      <img src="RW Houndmaster. CURS.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="containerIMG">
      <img src="RWg.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="containerIMG">
      <img src="UR Can't Lose.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="containerIMG">
      <img src="UR Mill copy.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="containerIMG">
      <img src="UR Mill.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="containerIMG">
      <img src="UR Prowess 3-0 (6-0).jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="containerIMG">
      <img src="UR Spells 4x overload.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="containerIMG">
      <img src="UR Spells.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="containerIMG">
      <img src="WRb creatures.jpeg">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this do? If so (just add height: ___) some pixels that you think fine to the `img` selector. Rest is fine.

The original issue you had was `difference in heights of various images`. Floats don't work properly in that case. Either you give a certain height (for all your images) to follow & keep `width: auto` (which you tried to give a fixed value) or use `flexbox`. But, I think with more than a certain number of images, that won't be a proper solution as it would try to fit all images - `in 1 single row, or column`.

```css
img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%
}
h1  {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 1.66%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Photo Blog</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="photogrid.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <h1>Gabe's Decks</h1>
    
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/06/20/25/dog-3204497_960_720.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg">
    <img src="RW Houndmaster. CURS.jpeg">
    <img src="RWg.jpeg">
    <img src="UR Can't Lose.jpeg">
    <img src="UR Mill copy.jpeg">
    <img src="UR Mill.jpeg">
    <img src="UR Prowess 3-0 (6-0).jpeg">
    <img src="UR Spells 4x overload.jpeg">
    <img src="UR Spells.jpeg">
    <img src="WRb creatures.jpeg">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not gonna work... What do you do if the image is basicly `height: 10px` and `width: 2000px` ? Your solution is not flexible

Comment: I assume such a banner would soundly never come to set of heap of images tbh :)

Comment: Still... You never know specialy if it comes from users. And it may create gaps horizontaly from the moment you dont fix width as well